# Ruby: Overriding the Constant (scope) Resolution Operator? (::)

Tags: ruby

According to [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) it's possible to override the constant resolution operater in Ruby. (Scroll down to the bottom of the page.) Is that true? If so, how do I do that and why would I ever want to?

Comment: "why would I ever want to?" - to make everybody hate you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Ruby Programming Language* lists only these operators as definable:

```
! ~ +                  # Boolean NOT, bitwise complement, unary plus
**                     # Exponentiation
-                      # Unary minus (define with-@)
* / %                  # Multiplication, division, modulo (remainder)
+ -                    # Addition (or concatenation), subtraction
<< >>                  # Bitwise shift-left (or append), bitwise shift-right
&                      # Bitwise AND
| ^                    # Bitwise OR, bitwise XOR
< <= >= >              # Ordering
== === != =~ !~ <=>    # Equality, pattern matching, comparison
```

Source: *Yukihiro Matsumoto: “The Ruby Programming Language” pp. 102 (2008, First Edition)*

So i guess the webpage you cited is simply wrong.

Comment: Okay, yeah I thought that might be the case since I couldn't figure out how to make it work in IRB.